# dismiss or close a div permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><div class="warningBox">Is this your first time here? Remmeber to change your password!</div></a>
```

I currently have a simple css div that displays a message to all my new users. I want to offer them the option to **permanently** dismiss / close the message once they have finished reading it.

Comment: Various levels of permanence are possible... none of which are truly and absolutely permanent. per-session, per-cookie (or cookie analogy in local storage), per-IP (server side logs IP). Jeff has the code for hiding the div, but you need to provide the level of permanence.

Comment: Im guessing i'll probably use cookie level.

A good example would be the notice that this very website (stackoverflow) displays when a user registers a new account and signs in for the fist time. It displays a message like "Welcome new user, please update your profile", somehting like that, and there is an [X] which permanently closes the notice. How does that work?

Comment: Probably uses the extra bit that Jeff added. Your user account will have some sort of data tied to it, which means that the data can persist in a permanent record (well, as permanent as the account itself!). Ultimately, more persistent than cookies. But will only work if your site has the concept of membership/users.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide on click.

```
$('.warningBox').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

To dismiss the message permanently you'd have to add an ajax call to the `click()` event to send a request to your server and store inside your database or where ever that they clicked to dismiss the message either by a logged in name/id/ip/etc... and in your code to check that variable in your database to not show it again if so.

You can use cookies or sessions but they can be erased and thus temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Only cookies or sessions can do this. On a separate note, a DIV (block element) tag shouldn't be placed inside an A (inline element) tag. Use a SPAN instead and apply "display: inline-block" via CSS.